# gst-launch-1.0 and GStreamer version mismatch

Tags: linux, gstreamer, raspberry-pi3

I am using this script to install version 1.14 of GStreamer on a Raspberry Pi.

https://gist.github.com/Swap-File/d8511128930c93281f36f18d634f6748

I completely uninstall GStreamer from the pi before running the script.

The script clones `gstreamer` and a bunch of other related repos (`gst-plugins-base` `gst-plugins-good` `gst-plugins-bad` `gst-plugins-ugly` `gst-libav` `gst-omx` `gst-python` `gst-rtsp-server`) checksout branch 1.14 and make installs them.The script completes with no issues.

After the script completes I check the version of GStreamer installed with

```
gst-launch-1.0 --version
```

It gives the output

```
gst-launch-1.0 version 1.14.2
GStreamer 1.10.4
Unknown package origin
```

My questions are:

1. Why is there a mismatch between gst-launch-1.0 and GStreamer versions?
2. How do I get gst-launch-1.0 to version 1.14?

PS: The aim of this exercise is to get the webrtcbin plugin working on a Pi.

Comment: What is the output for `gst-launch-1.0 --gst-version`
 ?

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking into this. I get "GStreamer Core Library version 1.10.4"

Comment: I think its a mismatch in the version of the library you are installing. Try installing `GStreamer` without the script. Since its raspberry pi, the build system would be setup already. Else use Debian version of Linux and try installing GStreamer directly

Comment: Will give it a try and comment on how it goes. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's for future searchers

I built GStreamer from source in Ubuntu 22.04

After build `gst-launch-1.0` output

```
gst-launch-1.0 version 1.23.0
GStreamer 1.20.3
Unknown package origin
```

Showing a version mismatch, by running `ldconfig`, which refreshes library paths after adding the new libraries in `/usr/local/lib`

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Now `gst-launch-1.0` output

```
gst-launch-1.0 version 1.23.0
GStreamer 1.23.0 (GIT)
Unknown package origin
```